# Cannot pass argument to method using multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

My program takes several arguments where one of them is called `challenges` which receives integer value from the command line. I want to use `multiprocessing` by passing the value of `challenges` to a self-defined method `generation`:

```
import multiprocessing

gen = generator.GenParentClass()
mlp = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
X, y = mlp.imap_unordered(gen.generation, [args.challenges])
```

The method `generation` in class `GenParentClass` has this simple signature:

```
def generation(self, num):
   #some stuff
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiments.py", line 194, in <module>
    X, y = mlp.imap_unordered(gen.generation, [args.challenges])
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 668, in next
    raise value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Everything seems to me correct!! Any help os appreciated.

Comment: Is `gen` a class or is it an instance of one?

Comment: @martineau `gen` is an instance of `GenParentClass` class

Comment: When I make it an instance of a stand-in class with a `generation()` method, I get a different error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`. Please [edit] your question and add enough code to recreate the problem. See [**_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note I also added an `if __name__ == '__main__':` at the right place in the code for the main task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multiprocess` module serializes (`pickles`) the arguments to `imap_unordered`.  It appears that the function `gen.generation` is an instance method (defined within a class), which means it cannot be pickled, hence your error.

Edit: Here is a possible workaround that defines the function outside of the class, and adds additional argument(s) to that function, which are filled in using `partial` from `itertools`:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

class GenParentClass(object):
    a = None
    b = None
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

# define this outside of GenParentClass (i.e., top level function)
def generation(num, x, y):
    return x+y+num

gen = GenParentClass(3, 5)
mlp = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
R = mlp.imap_unordered(partial(generation, x=gen.a, y=gen.b), [1,2,3])
print([r for r in R])   # prints "[9, 10, 11]"
```

More information on pickle-ability is available [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

More information on functools is available [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html).

Edit 2: If you use `multiprocess.Pool` and the function definition uses qualified variable names `self.a` and `self.b`, you can do this without rewriting the function outside the class, but you won't be able to retrieve the output, and the state of gen2 will not change (defeating the purpose of calling the function at all).

```
gen2 = GenParentClass(4, 6)
p = {}
for key in range(5):
    p[key] = multiprocessing.Process(target = GenParentClass.altgen, args = (gen2, key,))
    p[key].start()

for key in p:
    p[key].join()
```

Comment: Correct. Is there a workaround without having to change the class?

Comment: I was able to do this using `multiprocessing.Process`, on the condition that the variables `a` and `b` are qualified in the `altgen` function (see Edit 2 above), but the problem is that you cannot retrieve the output.