# multiprocessing for class method

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing for a class method. I found out from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230719/7902058) that `Pool` in `multiprocessing` cannot pickle class methods directly but there is a workaround for that by defining a function outside the class, and adds an additional argument(s) to that function (Similar suggestion is also on this [blog](http://www.rueckstiess.net/research/snippets/show/ca1d7d90)). Hence, I tried to achieve that by the following simple program which has `MyClass` where I want to parallel `fun`. However, I am not getting any results (there is no bug). It seems I am missing something but I feel I am almost there! Any fix is really appreciated.

```
import multiprocessing


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fun(self, myList):
        print myList


def unwrap_fun(obj, myList):
    return obj.fun(myList)


obj = MyClass()
mlp = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
mlp.imap_unordered(unwrap_fun, (obj, range(1, 10)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `close()` and `join()` from your main process.  Try this:

```
import multiprocessing

class MyClass:
    def fun(self, myList):
        print myList

def unwrap_fun(myList):
    obj = MyClass()
    return obj.fun(myList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mlp = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    mlp.imap_unordered(unwrap_fun, range(1, 10))
    mlp.close()
    mlp.join()
```